# Django templates won't load but HttpResponse will

Tags: python, django, web

I recently began learning django and have been running into some trouble and I can't figure out why.

My problem is quite simple: whenever I try to run my homepage with a template, it throws up a 404 error.

My file hierarchy is as such:

```
crm
 accounts
  templates
   accounts
    dashboard.html
  urls.py
  views.py
 crm
  urls.py
```

In crm/urls, I have

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('accounts.urls'))
```

Then in accounts/urls, there is,

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

And in views, I have

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html')
```

My dashboard.html is just a basic html file with a title and h1, that's it.

Also, whenever I change

```
return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html')
```

to

```
return HttpResponse('home')
```

in my home function, it decides to show.

Answer (score 0):

Your `dashboard.html` is inside a folder, so it should be referenced like `accounts/dashboard.html`

Relevant docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-render

In their example, they are using `polls/index.html` (scroll a bit up from the linked position in the docs). It is analogous to your `accounts/dashboard.html` in placement (both are in a subfolder as they should be).

---

Django looks for templates across multiple apps in the same way it searches for static files. Except that you can "see" static files being copied over to a separate folder with `manage.py collectstatic` while templates get "discovered" in place and not copied anywhere. In facg, if you are running `manage.py runserver` then the static files are also discovered in place, so the logic is the same.
One difference is that template loading can be changed by using a different set of loaders ([docs on template loaders](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#loading-templates), but by default (and for the majority of projects I guess) this similarity holds.